# Is there a way in Sprite Kit to get coordinates of a finger that doesn't move at the moment?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

To avoid unexpected game behaviour I'd like to know coordinates of all fingers on the touchscreen at any given moment. Is there a way of doing this?

For example get coordinates of the fist finger when second is taken off from the screen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yeah; you would record the last touches (in an instance variable) and update them when new ones come in.  If no new ones come in and the touches haven't ended then the finger(s) are stationary.  The finger position(s) is then available at any time, not just when a touch occurs.

Comment: Are you coding in Swift or Obj-C?

Comment: @trojanfoe, thanks for the idea - trying to implement it now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your assistance!

```
class GameScene : SKScene {

// stores all touches at any moment
var touchTracks : [UITouch] = []

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {

        self.touchTracks.append(touch)

    }
}


override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {

        var touchIndexToRemove : Int?
        for i in 0..<self.touchTracks.count {

            if self.touchTracks[i] == touch {
                touchIndexToRemove = i
            }
        }
        self.touchTracks.removeAtIndex(touchIndexToRemove!)

    }
}


override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    // touchesCancelled occurs e.g. when more than 5 fingers on iPhone is on the screen
    // Deregistering all tracks here
    self.touchTracks.removeAll()

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution based on trojanfoe's idea.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene : SKScene {

struct fingerTrackData {
    var fingerID : Int // used to identify fingers in other part of the code
    var lastLocation : CGPoint // location of each finger
}

// array that stores information about each finger coordinates
var fingerTracks : [fingerTrackData] = []


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        // getAvailableFingerID() returns available fingerID to avoid ID duplication
        self.fingerTracks.append(fingerTrackData(fingerID: self.getAvailableFingerID(), lastLocation: location))

    }
}


override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        self.updateFingerTracks(location)

    }

}


override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        // deregistering unnecessary finger tracks
        self.fingerTracks.removeAtIndex(self.getClosestFingerArrayIndexByLocation(location))

    }
}


override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    // touchesCancelled occurs e.g. when more than 5 fingers on iPhone is on the screen

    // Deregistering all tracks here
    self.fingerTracks.removeAll()

}


override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {

    // to see in console what is actually happening in array
    if fingerTracks.count > 0 {

        for fingerTrack in self.fingerTracks {

            print("Finger: \(fingerTrack.fingerID) Location: \(fingerTrack.lastLocation)")
        }

    } else {

        print("---")

    }
}


/*
 * Below are some helper functions for convenience
 */

func getClosestFingerArrayIndexByLocation (location: CGPoint) -> Int {

    var fingerTrackKeyToUpdate : Int = 0
    var shortestDistance : CGFloat = 100500 // some big number that is much bigger than screen size

    for (fingerTrackKey, fingerTrack) in self.fingerTracks.enumerate() {

        // calculating distance from previous record for each finger
        let calculatedDistance = sqrt(pow(fingerTrack.lastLocation.x - location.x,2) + pow(fingerTrack.lastLocation.y - location.y,2))

        // shortest one gives us finger ID
        if calculatedDistance < shortestDistance {

            shortestDistance = calculatedDistance

            fingerTrackKeyToUpdate = fingerTrackKey
        }

    }

    return fingerTrackKeyToUpdate
}


func updateFingerTracks(location: CGPoint) {

    let closestFingerArrayIndex = self.getClosestFingerArrayIndexByLocation(location)
    let fingerIDToUpdate = self.fingerTracks[closestFingerArrayIndex].fingerID

    self.fingerTracks[closestFingerArrayIndex] = fingerTrackData(fingerID: fingerIDToUpdate, lastLocation: location)

}


func getClosestFingerIdByLocation(location: CGPoint) -> Int {

    return self.fingerTracks[self.getClosestFingerArrayIndexByLocation(location)].fingerID

}


func getAvailableFingerID() -> Int {

    var availableFingerID : Int = 0

    if self.fingerTracks.count > 0 {

        var checkAgain = true

        while checkAgain {

            checkAgain = false

            for fingerTrack in self.fingerTracks {
                if availableFingerID == fingerTrack.fingerID {
                    checkAgain = true
                    availableFingerID++
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return availableFingerID
}

}
```

Comment: IOS automatically tracks touches through the various phases (began/moved/ended).

Comment: @0x141E, seems you're right, no need to store coords.